How to Ignore Certain Dependencies in Vue 3 watchEffect?
I'm using Vue 3 and I'm trying to use watchEffect to automatically track dependencies. However, I have a specific requirement where I need to ignore certain dependencies within the watchEffect so that changes to those dependencies do not trigger the effect to run again.
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue';

const a = ref(1);
const b = ref(2);
const c = ref(3);

watchEffect(() => {
  console.log('a:', a.value);
  console.log('b:', b.value);
  // I want to ignore changes to c
  console.log('c:', c.value);
});

// Changing values
a.value = 10; // This should trigger watchEffect
b.value = 20; // This should trigger watchEffect
c.value = 30; // This should NOT trigger watchEffect


In the above code, I want to ensure that changes to c do not trigger the watchEffect to run again. How can I achieve this?

Could maybe make a conditional on the onTrigger(e) part.

@kissu onTrigger is dev only

@loveyunk This is the case for regular watch() because of fine-grained controls

First, if you do
watchEffect(() => {
  console.log('a:', a.value)
  console.log('b:', b.value)
  console.log('c:', c.value)
})
a.value = 10
b.value = 20
c.value = 30

The callback will only be called twice, once for init and once for a b c are changed in the same tick.
See Vue Docs:

Similar to component updates, user-created watcher callbacks are batched to avoid duplicate invocations.

Okay I know that's just an example. Ignoring the mistake, I recommend using watchIgnorable from VueUse （although it's based on watch not watchEffect):
import { watchIgnorable } from '@vueuse/core'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const a = ref(1);
const b = ref(2);
const c = ref(3);

const { ignoreUpdates } = watchIgnorable(
  [a, b, c],
  () => {
    console.log('a:', a.value);
    console.log('b:', b.value);
    console.log('c:', c.value);
  },
  { immediate: true },
);

a.value = 10
b.value = 20
ignoreUpdates(() => {
  c.value = 30
})

Here is the full demo.
